# python vtk multiple renderers and orientation widgets

Tags: python, vtk

I am trying to render multiple views of the same actor with independent orientation widgets for each viewport. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to assign the widgets to the appropriate renderer and viewport. Here is a working example, where all of the orientation widgets end up in only one of the renderers:

```
import vtk

# Setup mesh mapper and actor
cylinder = vtk.vtkCylinderSource()
cylinder.SetResolution(8)
cylinderMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
cylinderMapper.SetInputConnection(cylinder.GetOutputPort())
cylinderActor = vtk.vtkActor()
cylinderActor.SetMapper(cylinderMapper)

# Create a render window, and set interaction styles
renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)
renderWindowInteractor.SetInteractorStyle(vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera())
renderWindow.SetSize(640, 480)

# Create multiple renderers and orientation widgets
axes_actor = vtk.vtkAxesActor()
orien_widgets = [vtk.vtkOrientationMarkerWidget() for _ in range(0,4)]
renderers = [vtk.vtkRenderer() for _ in range(0,4)]

# Create multiple views
for i,tup in enumerate(((0.0,0.0),
                        (0.5,0.0),
                        (0.0,0.5),
                        (0.5,0.5))):

    # Add renderer i
    renderers[i].SetViewport(tup[0],tup[1],
                             tup[0]+.5,tup[1]+.5)
    renderers[i].SetBackground(1, 1, 1)
    renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderers[i])
    renderers[i].AddActor(cylinderActor)

    # Add orientation widget and axes actor
    orien_widgets[i].renderer = renderers[i]
    orien_widgets[i].SetOutlineColor( 0.9300, 0.5700, 0.1300 )
    orien_widgets[i].SetOrientationMarker(axes_actor)
    orien_widgets[i].SetInteractor( renderWindowInteractor )
    orien_widgets[i].SetViewport(tup[0],tup[1],
                                 tup[0]+.5,tup[1]+.5)
    orien_widgets[i].EnabledOn()
    orien_widgets[i].InteractiveOn()
    renderers[i].ResetCamera()

# Render and interact
renderWindow.Render()
renderWindowInteractor.Start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is not right:

`orien_widgets[i].renderer = renderers[i]`

substitute it with:

`orien_widgets[i].SetCurrentRenderer(renderers[i])`